# Change button-text based on viewport width

Tags: html, css

I've got a button to close a lightbox in my homepage.

It's text says 'Close' and it is-right-aligned. However it can overlap with the headline-text when the viewport width is lower than 400 pixels.

So I want to exchange it with an 'X' using media-queries.

I tried `.button:before` which works but I can't get rid of the original 'Close' text this way.

How can I achieve this with only CSS?

Comment: Set `Close` also using `.button:before`, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vatckdwk/)

Comment: @Hedge , you can't use css to add or remove html text , that what js is meant to do , `insertusernamehere` gave you the right answer !

Comment: Yeah you are right. @insertusernamehere can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @ Alexander Solonik Css can add or remove html text see here  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBj2m/685/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the value of the button using the pseudo-element `:before` also for its default value "*Close*". Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<span class="button" title="Close"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.button:before {
    content: 'Close';
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
    .button:before {
        content: 'X';
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/vatckdwk/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a><span class="mob-view">X</span><span class="normal-view">close</span>
```

Using media query show:

```css
.mob-view {
    display:block;
}
.normal-view {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This would work but I can't change the button's HTML.

Comment: thats why there is need to use **:after** property

Answer (score 0):

Consider your button:

```
<button>Close</button>
```

Now let's replace 'Close' with 'X':

Set the below CSS in your media-query:

```
button {
    visibility: hidden;
}

button:after {
    content:'X'; 
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ZBj2m/685/

Hope this will work for you

Comment: This is a neat solution. There's one downside unfortunately: It doesn't work in IE9 or better. It seems that IE doesn't deal with  `visibility` as expected on pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="lightBox">
    <h1>Heading Goes Here</h1>
    <button id="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#lightBox{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    position:relative;
}
#close{
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    bottom:5px;
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
    height:25px
}
@media screen and (max-width:360px){
    #close{
        top:-10px !important;
        right:-10px !important;
        width:25px; 
        border-radius:25px;
        height:25px;
        text-indent:-99px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    #close:before{
        content:'X';
        text-indent: -14px;
        color: white;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s69mrq7b/)